# How to visualize a v-chart in an v-for where each object is the data of the v-chart?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuex, echarts

I want to generate dynamically some `v-charts` from `Echarts` in a `v-for`.

The data for the `v-or` is comming from the vuex store and is correct.

I get a dictionary, where each entry is an object

`bar{ title:'somCoolTitle', data:[d1,d2,d3,d4], ...}`.

I want to visualise each object bar as an chart, but my code wont't work. I doesn't get a fault. I only get an empty v-chart.

```
<template>
    <div v-for="(chart, index) in charts" v-bind:key="index">
        <v-chart
            v-bind:data="chart.bar.data"
            v-bind:name="chart.bar.title"
            v-bind:options="{responsive: false, maintainAspectRatio: false}"
        </v-chart>
    </div> 
</template>
```

Comment: These is my script part:
export default {
  components: {
    'v-chart': Echarts
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      bookmarks: 'getBookmarks',
      charts: 'getBookmarkChart'
    })
  },
name: Comp,
}

Answer (score 0):

As in [document](https://github.com/ecomfe/vue-echarts), you need to pass data and name as options to v-chart

```
<div v-for="(chart, index) in charts" v-bind:key="index">
    <v-chart
        v-bind:options="getChartOption(chart)"
    </v-chart>
</div>
```

You can use methods to format data:

```
methods: {
    getChartOption(chart) {
        return {
            title: {
                text: chart.bar.title
            },
            responsive: false,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            series: [
                {
                    name: chart.bar.title,
                    type: 'bar',
                    data: chart.bar.data
                }
            ],
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried it in a lot of ways, but it won't work. 
Now i build my own bar-chart with d3